# Create random variable in Terraform and pass it to GCE startup script

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to run a [`metadata_startup_script`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_instance.html#metadata_startup_script) when using Terraform to create a GCE instance.

This script is supposed to create a user and assign to this user a random password.

I know that I can create a random string in Terraform with something like:

```
resource "random_string" "pass" {
  length  = 20
}
```

And my `startup.sh` will at some point be like:

```sh
echo myuser:${PSSWD} | chpasswd
```

How can I chain the `random_string` resource generation with the appropriate script invocation through the `metadata_startup_script` parameter?

Here is the `google_compute_instance` resource definition:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "coreos-host" {
  name         = "my-vm"
  machine_type = "n1-stantard-2"
  zone         = "us-central1-a"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
      size = 20
      type = "pd-standard"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
        network_tier = "STANDARD"
    }
  }

  metadata_startup_script = "${file("./startup.sh")}"

}
```

where `startup.sh` includes the above line setting the password non-interactively.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the `google_compute_instance` resource definition?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I have updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to pass a Terraform variable into a templated file then you need to use a template.

In Terraform <0.12 you'll want to use the [`template_file` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html) like this:

```
resource "random_string" "pass" {
  length  = 20
}

data "template_file" "init" {
  template = "${file("./startup.sh")}"
  vars = {
    password = "${random_string.pass.result}"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "coreos-host" {
  name         = "my-vm"
  machine_type = "n1-stantard-2"
  zone         = "us-central1-a"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
      size = 20
      type = "pd-standard"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
        network_tier = "STANDARD"
    }
  }

  metadata_startup_script = "${data.template_file.startup_script.rendered}"
}
```

and change your `startup.sh` script to be:

```sh
echo myuser:${password} | chpasswd
```

Note that the template uses `${}` for interpolation of variables that Terraform is passing into the script. If you need to use `$` anywhere else in your script then you'll need to escape it by using `$$` to get a literal `$` in your rendered script.

In Terraform 0.12+ there is the new [`templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) which can be used instead of the `template_file` data source if you'd prefer:

```
resource "random_string" "pass" {
  length  = 20
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "coreos-host" {
  name         = "my-vm"
  machine_type = "n1-stantard-2"
  zone         = "us-central1-a"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
      size = 20
      type = "pd-standard"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
        network_tier = "STANDARD"
    }
  }

  metadata_startup_script = templatefile("./startup.sh", {password = random_string.pass.result})
}
```

---

As an aside you should also notice the warning on [`random_string`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/random/r/string.html):

> This resource does use a cryptographic random number generator.
>
> Historically this resource's intended usage has been ambiguous as the original example used it in a password. For backwards compatibility it will continue to exist. For unique ids please use random_id, for sensitive random values please use random_password.

As such you should instead use the [`random_password` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/random/r/password.html):

```
resource "random_password" "password" {
  length = 16
  special = true
  override_special = "_%@"
}
```

Comment: Awesome, `metadata_startup_script = templatefile("./startup.sh", {password = random_string.pass.result})` worked for me.